# Как извлечь и восстановить состояние JSON?

Tags: php, jquery, json

https://codepen.io/Bymbob/pen/OJENXpg

```
function save() {
  let dataArr = [];
  // проходимся во всем .row что внутри .container, то есть, по рядам
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.container .row')].forEach((row, idx) => {
    let seats = row.querySelectorAll('.seat'), 
        seatsData = []; 
    // для каждого ряда проходимся по местам (row.querySelectorAll('.seat'))
    [...seats].forEach(seat => {
      // собираем в массив информацию о каждом месте текущего ряда
      // зеленый, занято, selected - проверяем наличие класса
      // серый, забронировано, occupied- проверяем наличие класса
      seatsData.push({
        name: seat.innerText.trim(),
        selected: seat.classList.contains('selected'),
        occupied: seat.classList.contains('occupied'),
      });
    });
    // записываем в итоговый массив информацию по каждому ряду:
    // его индекс
    // информацию о его местах
    dataArr.push({
      rowIndex: idx,
      seats: seatsData
    });
  });
  console.log('stored data', dataArr);
  // ajax post запрос
  // store.php - файл что записывает в БД данные
  $.post("store.php", {data: dataArr});
}

if ( !empty($_POST['data']) ) {
  $data = json_encode($_POST['data']); // это теперь строка

  // тут запись в Базу Данных
}
```

Comment: так в чем, собственно, проблема?

Comment: JSON.parse() парсит строку в  JSON, JSON.stringify() JSON в строку